Dbt pre hook and post hook macro
This is my requirement.
I need to have pre hook macro which should get count(*), and sum(amount) before the model execution. I will pass the table name, column, filter condition as argument in pre-hook in dbt_project.yml.
I want these values to be calculated before model execution and use it in post-hook macro in the insert statement query defined it as value for source count and source aggregation.
Is there any way to do this?
The reason calculating these values at prehook is, days gets stored in the source in real time and if we calculate this after model execution via post hook, the source count is higher.
I have tried prehook macro by passing arguments in dbt_project.yml and tried to refer the pre hook macro in the post hook macro. Still it doesn't work
